# Selecting Pandas DataFrame Rows Based On Conditions

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am new to Python and getting to grips with Pandas. I am trying to perform a simple import CSV, filter, write CSV but can't the filter seems to be dropping rows of data compared to my Access query.

I am importing via the command below:

```
Costs1516 = pd.read_csv('C:......../1b Data MFF adjusted.csv')
```

Following import I get a data warning that the service code column contains data of multiple types (some are numerical codes others are purely text) but the import seems to attribute data type Object which I thought would just treat them both as strings and all would be fine....

I want the output dataframe to have the same structure as the the imported data (Costs1516), but only to include rows where 'Service Code' = '110'.

I have pulled the following SQL from Access which seems to do the job well, and returns 136k rows:

```
SELECT [1b Data MFF adjusted].*, [1b Data MFF adjusted].``[Service code]
FROM [1b Data MFF adjusted]
WHERE ((([1b Data MFF adjusted].[Service code])="110"));
```

My pandas equivalent is below but only returns 99k records:

```
Costs1516Ortho = Costs1516.loc[Costs1516['Service code'] == '110']
```

I have compared the two outputs and I can't see any reason why pandas is excluding some lines and including others....I'm really stuck...any suggested areas to look or approaches to test gratefully received.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, that's much clearer.

Comment: Try this: `Costs1516.loc[Costs1516['Service code'].astype(str) == '110']`

Comment: Oh my god it works, you hero Max thank you!

Comment: So it was trying to compare the number 110 with a text string '110' and not matching...? I guess the lesson is to set the data type at import...?

Comment: yes, that's how i undersand the warning: `I get a data warning that the service code column contains data of multiple types`...

Comment: @MaxU Yes strange though as the data in access was the same type...don't understand how some instances of 110 were interpreted as text and others as numerical in the same column.

Comment: same here, i've never had such an issue and never seen such a warning...